# JavaScript regexp matching

Tags: javascript, regex

When I use AJAX query to server, it return me string value. This string have predefined format like:

```
1|#||4|2352|updatePanel|updatePanelID

<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table id="requiredTable"/>
<tbody>

<tr>
<th>column1</th>
<th>column2</th>
</tr>

<tr style="cursor:pointer" onclick="FunctionName(11111, 22222, 3);">
<td>trColumn1Info</td>
<td>trColumn2Info</td>
</tr>

some other information
```

I want to get second arguments value of FunctionName by regular expression. I tryed to use next regexp, but it always return null:

```
var forTest = ajaxResultStr.match(/FunctionName\((\S*)\)/g);
alert(forTest);
```

Can anybody tell me, whats wrong in my pattern?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
FunctionName.*?,\s*(\w+)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/gD6iZ6/1)**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your regexp only matches when there are no spaces between `(` and `)`. Since there are spaces between the arguments, it doesn't match. Try:

```
var forTest = ajaxResultStr.match(/FunctionName\([^,]+,\s*([^,]+),.*\)/);
```

`forTest[1]` will contain the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

RegEx you can use

```
FunctionName\((.+?),(.+?),
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wU3fF9/1)

The last element of the result is your output.

```
//output
//["FunctionName(11111, 22222,", "11111", " 22222"]
```